# distorted & slow audio autput when booting with no HDMI on 3b+

Tags: audio, audio-playback

If I boot my Pi 3b+ with the HDMI cord plugged in then my audio sounds fine.  However, if I want to run it headless and I boot the device without the HDMI plug then the audio is very slow and distorted.  It still plays (through the headphone jack) but it sounds terrible.  Then if I plug in my HDMI cable and reboot it sounds perfect.

How?  Why?

Comment: Where the speakers are connected?

Comment: The speakers are plugged into the headphone jack.

Comment: Is there a way to restart the audio service?  It's like the playback speed is dramatically reduced - maybe there's a way to set the playback speed?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

uncomment the "hdmi_force_hotplug=1" line

uncomment the "hdmi_drive=2" line

Save changes to the file (ctrl+o, ctrl+x)

```
sudo reboot
```

That did the trick for me.

Comment: Where did you get this information and what does it do?